# Cómo abrir una imagen con ng-click

Tags: angularjs

¿Alguien tiene idea de cómo puedo abrir el archivo de la imagen con `ng-click`?

Lo que quiero hacer es que al dar clic en la etiqueta `img` se abra la imagen sola en el navegador.

```js
{
  "images": [
    "jpg/img.0.jpg",
    "jpg/img.1.jpg"
  ]
}
```

```html
<img ng-repeat="img in item.images" ng-src="{{img}}" ng-click="?"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Esto es muy fácil de lograr, sólo envuelve cada elemento `img` en un elemento `a` y establece el `href` de este último a la dirección de la imagen. Cuando hagas click en esta se abrirá la imagen.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ImagesCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.item = {
      "images": [
        "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1",
        "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/2"
      ]
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ImagesCtrl">
  <a ng-href="{{img}}" ng-repeat="img in item.images track by $index">
    <img ng-src="{{img}}">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias por responder. Al implementarlo cómo me haz explicado al dar clic en vez de llevarme a la imagen me lleva a mi ruta de error 404.

Comment: @AdrianoJosué Quizás porque no estas usando el modo html5 en tu aplicación o porque las url de las imagenes no son absolutas. Me inclino a pensar esto último. Inspecciona la página renderizada y prueba a abrir en una pestaña nueva la url generada en el atributo `href` para que veas.

Answer (score 0):

En [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14889674/1468942) hacen algo parecido a lo que necesitas. Vamos a adaptar esa respuesta a tu caso específico.

Partiendo de tu definición de la `img`:

```
<img ng-repeat="img in item.images" ng-src="{{img}}" ng-click="?"/>
```

En lugar de definir el `ng-click` en la `img` lo quitamos de ahí y ponemos el `ng-src` con las imagen directamente:

```
<img id="followbutton" ng-src="{{images.imgURL}}"/>
```

Lo envolvemos en un markdown `<a>` que define el `ng-click`:

```
<a ng-click="toggleImage(test)"><img id="followbutton" ng-src="{{images.imgURL}}"/></a>
```

Definimos la función `toggleImage()` (dentro de tu `app.controller`):

```
app.controller('NombreControladora', function CouponCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.followBtnImgUrl = 'jpg/img.0.jpg'
    $scope.test= [{imgUrl: "jpg/img.0.jpg", name:"sdf"}, 
                         {imgUrl: "jpg/img.1.jpg", name: "dfsd"}];


     $scope.toggleImage = function(test) {
         if(test.imgUrl === $scope.followBtnImgUrl) {
             test.imgUrl = merchant.$backupUrl;
         } else {
             test.$backupUrl = merchant.imgUrl;
             test.imgUrl = $scope.followBtnImgUrl;
         }
    };
});
```